# Why won't my softbody fall?

Tags: animation, soft-body

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2YFHXJDWJk) tutorial on how to make dynamic tinsel, and I can't seem to get the thing the fall. I've applied softbody physics to the mesh, and added the goal as the ends of the tinsel, but it still refuses to fall. I've tried:

- Flipping normals (Cntrl Shift N)
- Checking if anything has been baked
- Disabling the goal entirely (Absolutely nothing changes)

However, on opening a completely new Blender file, soft-body physics miraculously works, then stops working after a while

What would you recommend I try next? I followed the video step by step several times, and it never works

(I'm very new to Blender, so I've probably missed something stupid)

Thanks for any help

Comment: sometimes there can be some issue with tmp cache that is not updated, can you share some simplified file with the issue? use https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Good day Oliver,
Try adding Gravity (9.8 m/s2) under the FIELD WEIGHTS Tab of the Soft-Body section (located probably at the end)
Also Uncheck the GOAL option to release your object from hanging around and fall down with the specified Gravity and Mass.